# Realm executeTransaction() inside a loop?

Tags: android, realm

I am wondering if I can optimize the below code, or should I not bother any further?

1. Do I need the first `if`, where I check for number of items at all? Will it help?
2. Should I do `realm.executeTransaction()` inside `for` loop? I think it's better this way, since `executeTransaction()` can be expensive (? - not sure). On the other hand, I could omit the first `if` if I put it inside `for` loop.

Basically, I delete some of my items from Realm:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
if(realm.where(Alert.class).notEqualTo("exchange", AVERAGE_EXCHANGE).count() > 0) {
    realm.executeTransaction(r -> {
        for (Alert alert : realm.where(Alert.class).notEqualTo("exchange", AVERAGE_EXCHANGE).findAll()) {
            NetworkUtils.deleteAlertFromServer(alert);
            alert.deleteFromRealm();
        }
    });
}
realm.close();
```

Comment: Executing transaction is expensive and the loop being inside is better. No need for transaction if you don't do write.

Comment: So it seems this is as optimized as it can be. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for your questions:

1. You don't need `if`. Just do the logic inside the transaction.
2. Method `executeTransaction` is expensive, so do the loop inside the transaction.

You can do it like this:

```
realm.executeTransaction(r -> {
    RealmResults<Alert> alerts = realm.where(Alert.class).notEqualTo("exchange", AVERAGE_EXCHANGE).findAll();
    for (Alert alert : alerts) {
        NetworkUtils.deleteAlertFromServer(alert);
    }
    alerts.deleteAllFromRealm();
});
```